# Converting from .jpg to .pdf yields blank pages

Tags: file-conversion

I have some problems converting 180 JPG files into a single PDF. I'm using ImageMagick.

First, I resize the JPG files using `mogrify -resize 75% *.jpg` and the result looks fine.
After that, I run `convert *.jpg converted.pdf` and it works fine for the first 3-4 (out of 180) JPG files.

I don't understand why some of the images are properly converted, while most of them are blank...

LE: It won't even convert one image, it will still yield a single blank page PDF.

Comment: If you just convert one of of the non-working JPGs to a PDF, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

`convert` and `mogrify` are utilities in the [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) package. So if there are problems with it, you really need to take it to them.

However, there are many other ways of converting of images to PDF, including the "Create PDF" Quick Action in Catalina and later. It's possible to automate this process in shell scripts using the `automator` command (or `shortcut` in Monterey) to run your own Automator workflows.